# Is there a regex or other tool I can use to change a method call to a function call that encloses the previous expression?

Tags: c++, regex, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I'm working on making a change to a large C++ codebase where I need to change a method call to an equivalent function call, e.g. `someExpression.foo()` becomes `bar(someExpression)`.

A few more examples of the sort of transformation I'm looking for:

- `(itemA + itemB).foo()` becomes `bar(itemA + itemB)`
- `outerFunction(object->method(), arg2 + val, innerFunction(arg3)).foo()` becomes `bar(outerFunction(object->method(), arg2 + val, innerFunction(arg3)))`

Basically, the expression proceeding the method call to `foo()` could be fairly complex. But `foo()` comes up a lot of times in my codebase, so I'm really hoping there's some way I can automate this change rather than having to laboriously edit everything manually.

Can this be done with a regex? Or is there another tool I can use to make this change?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIATRA might provide it for you, but I'm not an expert on this.

Comment: it probably can be done with a regex, finding all your edge cases will be fun though.

Comment: It doesn't need to be perfect. Even if it only catches 80% of all of the instances of `foo()` it'd still be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

I've slapped together a regex that seems to work so far, based on the non-recursive parenthesis-balancing regex from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35271017/1079430)

```
([^\s\(]*(?:\((?:[^)(]|\((?:[^)(]|\((?:[^)(]|\([^)(]*\))*\))*\))*\))?)\.foo\(\)
```

That won't match any valid expression proceeding `.foo()` but will match most of them. There may be bugs with this regex, but I haven't found any or hit any mismatches so far. And it contains a capture group that can be used for replacement, i.e.: `bar(\1)`

I'm going to leave this question open though because there are almost certainly better methods than this.